# Using a jQuery image slider to a multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, slider, image

I have a image slider. It´s a simple one and has been done with js/jQuery.
When i open the homepage, it starts from image1 and it goes through all of them and then starts up the loop again.
The thing i don´t know how to accomplish is:
Is there a way that i can separate the slider from the .html page? The point is - can i make the slider to remember its current image and when i open another .html page to start from the current one in the previous page? 
For example i have 30 images loaded in the slider. 
The current one is image12 -> i load another .html page in the browser and the slider starts from image12, not from image1

Comment: What codes do you need exactly ? jQuery , slider.js or script.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rewrite to handle a setting value like startSlideShowFromImageNo
2. Set/Update a cookie on each slide change
3. Read that cookie on init of slideshow

Comment: Thank you this is a beginning. I will try to do it

Comment: Yeah, textual respons to textual question :-)...... but it shouldn't be that complex.... think I'll implement it on a something myself soon..

Comment: Hmm it´s exactly like that :) I am up to it right now but i cannot see any solution so far :( Please if you have anything in mind do not hesitate to share :-)

Comment: But i think that if i go this way for this issue, i mean using cookies , it won´t be able to mobile and tablet devices :-(

Comment: You should be able to use cookies on mobile devices..... Alternatively, pass the startImage param as url-param, but that involves updating all internal links

Comment: Or, if you are building backend aswell.... create a service that stores the slidenumber in session, and always provide this for user.